# I have a question about past tense

Tags: past-tense

I have a sentence:

> My grandfather **was** a model worker.

My question is: Is "My grandfather" alive or dead?

I wrote a sentence:

> I was a student.

Is it correct? Thanks in advance :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of context, there is nothing to indicate whether Grandfather is still alive or not. The speaker might be an older person talking about their family history, or a young person who will go on to say "...but now he has retired."

If you were once a student but are now, for example, in full-time employment, of course you can say "I was a student".